# How do I open an .sln file in older Visual Studio in C# code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I implemented a .NET application where the user browses for solution files. The user can choose to open these solution files in Visual Studio.

The problem is that the solutions need to be opened in Visual Studio 2008. Not in Visual Studio 2010 or above. This is necessary to keep the solution files in their original state.

All this should happen in C#. Bellow is the code but it opens the sln files with the default Visual Studio of the user.

```
if (file.EndsWith(".sln") && File.Exists(file))
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(file);
```

Comment: A .sln file is a pretty simple text file.  Have a look-see with a text editor, Notepad is fine.  See the version number?  You can change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that it isn't necessary to detect the original version, in which the solutions were made. All solutions are created in Visual Studio 2008 by default.

Find the solution in the code bellow:

Add the reference EnvDTE.dll and `using EnvDTE;` in your code

```
public static void OpenSlnFile(string file)
{
    System.Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.9.0");
    EnvDTE.DTE dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)System.Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    dte.MainWindow.Visible = true;

    dte.Solution.Open(file);
}
```

Comment: Whilst this may be work for your problem **today** it would be better to add the version check so that the program does the correct job in the future, or gives an error message when the assumptions about versions are not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are just launching a new process indicating file to the file and letting Windows to handle everything for you. Windows know that .SLN files should be opened with default associated program and that's it.

To change this behavior you have to programmatically analize the version of your SLN file, and based on SLN version open concrete version of VisualStudio passing as parameter the SLN file.

So you would need to emulate from your C# code something like:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE>devenv.exe "C:\PATH\SOLUTION.sln"
```

It could look somehow like this:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var slnPath = @"C:\PATH\SOLUTION.sln";
        var slnVersion = GetVersion(slnPath);

        switch (slnVersion)
        {
            case ...:
                break;
            case 14:
                var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe";
                startInfo.Arguments = slnPath;
                Process.Start(startInfo);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Which program launched on clent depend on the registry key HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.Launcher.sln (referenced by HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.sln)

When you open the file, it runs "c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\VSLauncher.exe" "%1", which reads the version from the .sln file and open the correct version.
About .sln file structure you can read at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165951.aspx